# Failed when using drawText() in main() function

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        QRect r(0,8,32,16);
        QImage img(32,32,QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
        img.fill(Qt::Red);
        QPainter p;
        p.begin(&img);
        QPen pen;
        pen.setColor(QColor(0,0,0));
        p.setPen(pen);
        p.drawText(r,QString::number(i));
        p.end();
        QString str;
        str.clear();
        str.append("../../bmp/");
        str.append(QString::number(2));
        str.append(".bmp");
        img.save(str);
        return a.exec();
}
```

When gose to `p.drawText(r,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(i));`,Qt reports `Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823.` 
But if I use other functions like drawRect or drawLine ,no faults are reported, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font support must be part of GUI subsystem, both Qt framework-wise and  platform-wise, assuming it's a XWindows application, Wayland or MS Windows.

Try replace  QCoreApplication with QApplication and add GUI to configuration. Sadly, in case of Linux platform, you would require an active GUI server available.